# When to use saveInstanceState() method?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-state

I know `saveInstanceState()` is used to store activity variables, text in EditText, etc.

But I have a doubt that should I save state of view?

Let me give you a scenario. My view has 3 buttons. On clicking one of them, a WebView is displayed to user (in same activity). Now if app gets killed, should I save state that user was displayed WebView when app got killed and when activity gets recreated display WebView instead of buttons?

Other scenario is, I have 3 tabs in view. Selecting each tab shows different view. As explained in above case again should I save that user has last selected this tab?

It will be best if you can explain the cases where I should and should not save activity state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operating system knows when it should re-create your app's previous state (the screen orientation changed or your app was killed in the background by the OS) and when to create a new instance (the user left your app with the back button). The `onRestoreInstanceState()` method is only called when there's a state to restore (when the system is restoring a previous state, as opposed to creating a new instance of the activity).

The short answer, then, is that if you override `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`, the system will call them when appropriate, and **you don't have to worry about deciding when you "should" save state**.

When overriding `onSaveInstanceState()`, yes, you should save everything about your activity's state. This is the method being used during screen orientation change. Think about it - if you rotate your phone, do you expect the current app to change tabs, or the screen that just opened to disappear?

For more information, see [the Android documentation on recreating an activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

Comment: My app don't need to support orientation changes. It supports portrait only.

Comment: I am not clear even about if I should use these method. Because if put app in background by clicking home button and open app again it shows me last state. Then why do I manually need to save and restore?

Comment: If you put your app in the background by clicking the home button, it won't necessarily be killed entirely (just paused). If you put your app in the background and then open enough other applications that your phone needs to kill your app to regain the memory and _then_ reopen your app, you'll have lost your state. As the user, you haven't really done anything differently between those two scenarios, but different things are going on behind the scenes and your app should support both.

Comment: I implemented these methods in an activity and just saved EditText's text. I pressed home button. App is in background. Kept pressing home to see list of apps in background. Killed my app. Opened it again. Programmatically opened the activity(using Intent) I was in before putting app in background. As per what you say, it should have saved bundle and call onRestoreInstanceState(). But it did not.

Comment: @Akash Maybe try it out in the main activity of an app, first. As well, the system may have recognized that you manually closed the application and acted accordingly (personally, I wouldn't expect state to save if I killed the app from the recent tasks list).

Comment: Let me put my in background. Open so many apps so that ultimately my app gets killed. And see what happens then.

Comment: I killed my app from emulator DDMS perspective. And opening it again called onRestoreInstanceState. Now, I am satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

I have not done very much research on savedIntanceState on `app gets killed`. But yes you may save maybe a integer variable (referring to which button is clicked) in state, so that when activity is recreated, you know which webview used to be shown (or none). Same goes to your second situation.

**Some extra use case of saved instance state:**

One of the most used scenario is during user switches orientation, say you have a couple of edit texts on screen, their holding texts would be gone if user change his device orientation. Saved instance state helps you to recover the entered texts.

Another situation is you will most likely have a few class variable in your activity, probably used to save what user has done, or some temporary list object in a list activity. Saving those variables also prevents you from needing to recover the data on orientation change.

Comment: I am not sure if I should use these methods to save and restore state. One reason being is my app does not support orientation other than portrait. Second reason is when I put app in background and open again it shows me last state from where I put it in background. for example, I selected a particular tab before putting app in background and after opening app it showed me that tab as selected which is not default selection. Lets talk about third case of app getting killed by OS. If app was killed by OS and then user opens app again I believe that user should be directed to home screen.

Comment: Because app was not in background ,it was closed. Opening a closed app should display home screen only. Am I right in this third case?

Comment: Personally i would try my best to keep user at his last visited position (By using db or sharedpref). When user press home, most of them would prefer to have the same screen when they come back. OS kills your app because memory is not enough, and that is not something user would aware of, they would expect to see what shown when they left using home button. I am not very sure on the possibility to recover savedInstanceState after OS kills your app.

Comment: But when I press home and open app I see the last state only which is the ultimate goal. OS handles it. Then why should I do it manually?

Comment: They keep it, while your app is still there in memory, you never know when OS would kill it. Of course recovering saved state after getting killed may not works, I'm not sure on that, hence I suggest SharedPref or Db over savedInstanceState.

Comment: @Akash whether that behaviour that you're seeing happens depends on what other apps you open in the meantime and how much memory they use. It also depends on the phone - your app should support users whose phones don't have a lot of memory just as well as it supports those that do.

Comment: @ChorWaiChun If you check out the documentation I linked in my answer, `onSaveInstanceState()/onRestoreInstanceState()` are pretty much specifically for the situation where the OS kills an app (and differentiating between that and the user backing out of it), so yes, it works :)