# How to save edit text field when activity restarts

Tags: java, android, android-studio

trying to create part of my app but have hit a wall. When you add a drop down from a list you go to a new activity to add another. Then when you return to the activity the previous drop down selection has gone.

Is there a way of saving the first drop down selection so that when you return to the activity it is still there?

Below is the code where I am adding the option from the drop down.

```
public String s;

TextView myLocationText;
TextView myLocationText2;
TextView myLocationText3;
TextView myLocationText4;
TextView myLocationText5;

EditText textCheck;
EditText textCheck2;
EditText textCheck3;
EditText textCheck4;
EditText textCheck5;

static int i = 1;

TextView testView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_activity_second);

    s = getIntent().getStringExtra("SELECTED_ACTIVITY");

    //Display selected activity in log
    Log.d("SecondActivity::" + s, "Extra");

    textCheck = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData);
    textCheck2 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData2);
    textCheck3 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData3);
    textCheck4 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData4);
    textCheck5 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData5);

    //Display selected activity
    if ((textCheck.getText().toString().equals("")) && i == 1) {
        myLocationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData);
        myLocationText.setText(s);
        i++;
    } else if ((textCheck2.getText().toString().equals("")) && i == 2) {
        myLocationText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData2);
        myLocationText2.setText(s);
        i++;
    } else if ((textCheck3.getText().toString().equals("")) && i == 3) {
        myLocationText3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData3);
        myLocationText3.setText(s);
        i++;
    } else if ((textCheck4.getText().toString().equals("")) && i == 4) {
        myLocationText4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData4);
        myLocationText4.setText(s);
        i++;
    } else if ((textCheck5.getText().toString().equals("")) && i == 5) {
        myLocationText5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData5);
        myLocationText5.setText(s);
        i++;
    }
```

I have edited my code from the code above, its cleaner and I have included the save features I believe are needed but still not having a lot of luck. See below.

```
public String s;

EditText textCheck;
EditText textCheck2;
EditText textCheck3;
EditText textCheck4;
EditText textCheck5;

static int i = 1;

TextView testView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_activity_second);
    s = getIntent().getStringExtra("SELECTED_ACTIVITY");

    //Display selected activity in log
    Log.d("SecondActivity::" + s, "Extra");

    //Look for saved text from activity
    textCheck = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData);
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        String editTextString = savedInstanceState.getString("textCheck");
        textCheck.setText(editTextString);
    }
    textCheck2 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData2);
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        String editTextString2 = savedInstanceState.getString("textCheck2");
        textCheck2.setText(editTextString2);
    }
    textCheck3 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData3);
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        String editTextString3 = savedInstanceState.getString("textCheck3");
        textCheck3.setText(editTextString3);
    }
    textCheck4 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData4);
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        String editTextString4 = savedInstanceState.getString("textCheck4");
        textCheck4.setText(editTextString4);
    }
    textCheck5 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData5);
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        String editTextString5 = savedInstanceState.getString("textCheck5");
        textCheck5.setText(editTextString5);
    }

    //Display selected activity
    if ((textCheck.getText().toString().equals("")) && i == 1) {
        textCheck.setText(s);
        i++;
    } else if ((textCheck2.getText().toString().equals("")) && i == 2) {
        textCheck2.setText(s);
        i++;
    } else if ((textCheck3.getText().toString().equals("")) && i == 3) {
        textCheck3.setText(s);
        i++;
    } else if ((textCheck4.getText().toString().equals("")) && i == 4) {
        textCheck4.setText(s);
        i++;
    } else if ((textCheck5.getText().toString().equals("")) && i == 5) {
        textCheck5.setText(s);
        i++;
    } else if (i == 6){
        return;
    }
}

//Save text within activity
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("textCheck", textCheck.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("textCheck2", textCheck2.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("textCheck3", textCheck3.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("textCheck4", textCheck4.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("textCheck5", textCheck5.getText().toString());
}

//Retrieve previous activity text
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState!=null) {
        textCheck.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("textCheck"));
        textCheck2.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("textCheck2"));
        textCheck3.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("textCheck3"));
        textCheck4.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("textCheck4"));
        textCheck5.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("textCheck5"));
    }
}
```

Comment: use `onSaveInstanceState(bundle)` and get it back in `onCreate(bundle)` bundle.

Comment: this code will help you: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/09/onsaveinstancestate-and.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use saveInstanceState() method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208611/when-to-use-saveinstancestate-method)

Answer (score 1):

Override `OnSaveInstanceState()` in activity and put all the value required in the bundle using unique key. Like :

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("EDITTEXT", mEditText.getText().toString());
}
```

Retrieve the value in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` using the same key. Like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_activity_second);
    textCheck = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData);
    //this will be false for first time but will be true when activity recreates.
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        String editTextString = savedInstanceState.getString("EDITTEXT");
        textCheck.setText(editTextString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I have created the onSaveInstanceState method and also added the code in my onCreate method, however when I return to the activity the added text from the drop down still seems to have disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Save the EditText's content in a shared preference

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(preferences1,
MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("text", "editTextsString");
editor.commit();
```

Then on activity create or resume, call the shared preference with:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(preferences1, MODE_PRIVATE); 
 String Text = prefs.getString("text", null);
```

And set the edit text to the the string variable: Text

Comment: When you have `onSaveInstanceState()` why to do costly operation like sharedPreference.

Comment: It's the only method I could think of to solve op's problem - it's not the smoothest perhaps, but I think it would achieve op's request.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public String s;

TextView myLocationText;
TextView myLocationText2;
TextView myLocationText3;
TextView myLocationText4;
TextView myLocationText5;

EditText textCheck;
EditText textCheck2;
EditText textCheck3;
EditText textCheck4;
EditText textCheck5;

static int i = 1;

TextView testView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_activity_second);

    s = getIntent().getStringExtra("SELECTED_ACTIVITY");

    //Display selected activity in log
    Log.d("SecondActivity::" + s, "Extra");

    textCheck = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData);
    textCheck2 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData2);
    textCheck3 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData3);
    textCheck4 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData4);
    textCheck5 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData5);

    //Display selected activity
    if ((textCheck.getText().toString().equals("")) && i == 1) {
        myLocationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData);
        myLocationText.setText(s);
        i++;
    } else if ((textCheck2.getText().toString().equals("")) && i == 2) {
        myLocationText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData2);
        myLocationText2.setText(s);
        i++;
    } else if ((textCheck3.getText().toString().equals("")) && i == 3) {
        myLocationText3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData3);
        myLocationText3.setText(s);
        i++;
    } else if ((textCheck4.getText().toString().equals("")) && i == 4) {
        myLocationText4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData4);
        myLocationText4.setText(s);
        i++;
    } else if ((textCheck5.getText().toString().equals("")) && i == 5) {
        myLocationText5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sampleTextData5);
        myLocationText5.setText(s);
        i++;
    }


}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("textCheck", textCheck.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("textCheck2", textCheck2.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("textCheck3", textCheck3.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("textCheck4", textCheck4.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("textCheck5", textCheck5.getText().toString());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState!=null) {
        textCheck.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("textCheck"));
        textCheck2.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("textCheck2"));
        textCheck3.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("textCheck3"));
        textCheck4.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("textCheck4"));
        textCheck5.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("textCheck5"));
    }
}
```

Just copy and paste this code. Hope It will work.

Comment: Unfortunately not, added the two bottom methods but still its not saving.

Comment: No error, the app continues to work as well. Because of i++ it will add the other activity to the field below, however the field above still seems to be blank upon return to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use OnSaveInstanceState() to save the value during restart of an activity .

use below code : 

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    bundle.putString("Key","Edit Text value");
}

and get the data using  below code :


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        String value = savedInstanceState.getString("Key");
    }
}
```